# Java 8 - accumulate and create new collection

Tags: list, collections, java-8, accumulator, collectors

Using java 8 I want to create a new collection from a list and accumulate a sum along the way.

The source list consists of objects that look something like this:

```
class Event {
  String description;
  double sum;
}
```

With an example list like this:

```
{ { "desc1", 10.0 }, {"desc2", 14.0 }, {"desc3", 5.0 } }
```

The resulting list should look like this

- desc1, 10.0, 10.0
- desc2, 14.0, 24.0
- desc3,  5.0, 29.0

I know how to sum up to get a final sum, in this case 29.0, but I want to create the result list and at the same time accumulate the sum along the way.

How can I do this with Java8?

Comment: How would you make just one of the elements of the result list?

Answer (score 4):

You could do this by implementing your own collector to perform the mapping and summing together.  Your streaming code would look like this:

```
List<SummedEvent> summedEvents = events.stream().collect(EventConsumer::new, EventConsumer::accept, EventConsumer::combine).summedEvents();
summedEvents.forEach((se) -> System.out.println(String.format("%s, %2f, %2f", se.description, se.sum, se.runningTotal)));
```

For this I've assumed a new class `SummedEvent` which also holds the running total.  Your collector class would then be implemented something like this:

```
class EventConsumer {
    private List<SummedEvent> summedEvents = new ArrayList<>();
    private double runningTotal = 0;

    public void accept(Event event) {
        runningTotal += event.sum;
        summedEvents.add(new SummedEvent(event.description, event.sum, runningTotal));
    }
    public void combine(EventConsumer other) {
        this.summedEvents.addAll(other.summedEvents);
        this.runningTotal += other.runningTotal;
    }

    public List<SummedEvent> summedEvents() {
        return summedEvents;
    }
}
```

Comment: ... thinking of it, I'm not sure if it could be done in parallel in one pass.

Comment: I don't see at all how it could be done in parallel as it requires ordering, I presume the OP was aware of this though

Comment: Well `parallelPrefix` does this "ordered" accumulation in parallel. So I assume it could be done with some extra code.

Comment: I had a look at parallelPrefix- "some" code = "quite a lot" of code, most of which I don't understand :)

Comment: You are essentially looking for a prefix operation (which does work in parallel if your operator is associative.)  Stream does not support a prefix operation but there is one for arrays.

Comment: @Alexis C.: `parallelPrefix` works for arrays because you can easily iterate over an array twice. Doing the same with an arbitrary `Stream` is not possible.

Comment: @Holger This is what I understood looking at the source code of `IntCumulateTask`. As I get it, each FJ task works on its own range of values in the array and apply the reduction. And yes, that would indeed not be possible for Stream as once you get the value it's kind of "consumed".

Comment: @Alexis C.: the point is, the prefix operation is performed on sub-arrays and each of these operations produces a constant value which has to be applied to the follow-up sub-arrays in a second step. This second step is not possible with streams.

Answer (score 3):

If you will run your pipeline sequentially, you can use this little hack with `peek`.

```
double[] acc = {0};
List<CustomEvent> list = originalList.stream()
                                     .peek(e -> acc[0] += e.sum)
                                     .map(e -> new CustomEvent(e, acc[0]))
                                     .collect(toList());
```

**Be aware that you'll get wrong results if
 the stream is run in parallel.**

However I'm not sure if the pipeline can be run in parallel in one pass, but assuming the underlying list has a fast access to element at index `i` you can do it like this:

```
double[] acc = originalList.stream().mapToDouble(e -> e.sum).toArray();
Arrays.parallelPrefix(acc, Double::sum);

List<CustomEvent> lx = IntStream.range(0, originalList.size())
                                .parallel()
                                .mapToObj(i -> new CustomEvent(originalList.get(i), acc[i]))
                                .collect(toList());
```

`parallelPrefix` will apply the reduction you are looking for the sums. Then you just have to stream the indices and you map each event to its corresponding accumulated sum.

Comment: Don't code like this (where 'this' means writing code that will silently break if anyone ever turns your stream parallel).  This is the 2015 version of coding with data races because "I'll never use threads."

Comment: @BrianGoetz You mean the `peek` version? Yes, I don't like to use it anyway as it's often sign of side-effects; maybe I wasn't enough clear in my answer, I edited that.

Comment: @AlexisC. Does this mean that the parallelPrefix variant does not have any problem when running in parallell?

Comment: @svaret `parallelPrefix` runs already in parallel (as its name suggests). No you won't have any problem with it.

Comment: @svaret Just as a note, running in parallel does not mean that it'll always be faster than a sequential computation. For small arrays the overhead of creating all this threading stuff could be expensive.

Comment: @AlexisC. Yes I understand. I am quite new to the way of thinking (the functional way) and as long as I am aware of if there is no need for this to run in parallell I can stick with the variant that I feel makes the most understandable code.

Comment: @svaret Yes it'll come with experience, I guess. If you are using my first "solution", it's not a functional way as the `peek` method have side-effects. Functional programming languages have as a rule of thumb that a function should never have side-effects.

Comment: @AlexisC. A question: _Then you just have to stream the indices..._
So I have to add code to match acc and lx ? These two are separate right?